# how to send multiple data with ajax without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get 2 or more data from database with php and show on the index page. I did it with these codes but I don't want to use 2 php pages and 2 functions.

here my index.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  gonder();
  var int=self.setInterval("gonder()",500);
  var int=self.setInterval("gonder1()",500);
});

function gonder()
{
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'maot.php',
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#maot").html(msg);
        }
   });
}
function gonder1(){
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'durum.php',
    success: function (msg1) {
         $("#durum").html(msg1);
         }
   });
 }
```

in here I used 2 functions but I could not figure out how to show 2 variables on separate divs.

here 2 php pages I used

durum.php

```
<?php include ( "dataconn.php" );

$smntnlscada = mysql_query ("Select * FROM kompresor");
$scada = mysql_fetch_assoc($smntnlscada);

$durum = $scada['durum'];
if ($durum==0) {
$durum1='no';
} elseif ($durum==1) {
$durum1='yes';
} elseif ($durum==2) {
$durum1='error';
}

$manuel = $scada['manuel'];
if ($manuel==0) {
$manuel1='oto';
} elseif ($manuel==1) {
$manuel1='manuel';
}


echo $durum1;
```

?>

maot.php

```
<?php include ( "dataconn.php" );

$smntnlscada = mysql_query ("Select * FROM kompresor");
$scada = mysql_fetch_assoc($smntnlscada);

$durum = $scada['durum'];
if ($durum==0) {
$durum1='no';
} elseif ($durum==1) {
$durum1='yes';
} elseif ($durum==2) {
$durum1='error';
}

$manuel = $scada['manuel'];
if ($manuel==0) {
$manuel1='oto';
} elseif ($manuel==1) {
$manuel1='manuel';
}

echo $manuel1;
```

?>

My question is how can I get 2 variables from `ajax` and show them separate divs without refreshing the page. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: set die(); at the end of  maot.php and durum.php  files

Comment: It may be helpful if you included the relevant parts of your existing markup, especially the `div` elements you are hoping to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your php file :

```
$to_send = array();
array_push($to_send, $durum1, $manuel1);
print json_encode($to_send);
```

in javascript success function :

```
var data = $.parseJSON(msg1);
$("#durum").html(data[0]);
$("#maot").html(data[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function gonder(div){
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'getmydiv.php',
    data : 'selecteddiv='+div,
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#'+div).html(msg);
        }
});
}
```

Then in your PHP function look at $_POST['selecteddiv'] to see if you are doing 'durum' or 'moat' and process accordingly.